# Which DOM events can be bound to a DIV element?

Tags: events, dom, html

As per question in the title...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a complete list of DOM events [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events), which includes browser-specific and touch-interface events as well. All the Mouse and Keyboard events can be attached to a div, which are:

> mousedown, mouseup, mouseover, mousemove, mouseout, click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup

Answer (score 9):

There are various events which can be performed on `div` tags such as

```
ondrag,
ondragcenter,
ondragleave,
ondrop,
ondragover,
ondragstart,
ondragend,
onscroll
```

Answer (score 6):

event Attributes you can use:

```
onclick, ondblclick, onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseout, 
onmouseover, onmouseup, onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup
```

See more about the `<div>` tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp), and general `DOM` events [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).