# Adapting a javascript code for Text-To-Speech and Streamlabs

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I'm setting up a new Alert Box from streamlabs.com, and I want to customize it: When there is a new follower, there is a text-to-spech of the name of the follower! But I have time to learn javascript or any other languages.

I've found this https://codepen.io/sgestrella/pen/MxJLXm, which is near what I want, but when I copy/paste the code into https://streamlabs.com/dashboard#/alertbox, it didn't work! So I suppose that I have to change some code, but I don't know how

The code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <textarea id="txtFld">I love the sound of my computer-generated voice.</textarea>
  <div>
    <button type="button" id="speakBtn">Speak</button>
  </div>
</div>

 <div id="txtFld">{userMessage}</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="speakBtn">Speak</button>
  </div>
```

```
let speakBtn, txtFld;
function init(){
  speakBtn = qs("#speakBtn");
  txtFld = qs("#txtFld");
  speakBtn.addEventListener("click",talk,false);
  if (!window.speechSynthesis) {
    speakBtn.disabled = true;
    qs("#warning").style.display = "block";
  }
}
function talk(){
  let u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  u.text = txtFld.value;
  speechSynthesis.speak(u);
}
// Reusable utility functions
function qs(selectorText){
  //saves lots of typing for those who eschew Jquery
  return document.querySelector(selectorText);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
  try {init();} catch (error){
    console.log("Data didn't load", error);}
});
```

I expect the code to start on its own when I run the test, but actually it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to remember that you can't use the same id for more than one element, since id is unique.
So change this line:

```
<div id="txtFld">{userMessage}</div>
```

As for your question:
In order to trigger a div textContent change you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47379026/6525081).
Now if we combine it all together we will get something like that:

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var element = document.getElementById('example');

  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
  var observer = new MutationObserver(talk);
  observer.observe(element, {
      childList: true
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    element.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    element.textContent = 'Hello Space!';
  }, 2000);

function talk(){
  let u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  u.text = element.textContent;
  speechSynthesis.speak(u);
}

});
</script>
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Hope this put you on the right way and good luck!

I made a codepen that you can play with [here](https://codepen.io/AMeshu/pen/jjavQL).