# On load instead of document ready with other javascript on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this bit of code going that looks for a certain class and adds the QTY text inside the class. I have to do it this way as I don't have access to the base HTML code for this portion of the site, but rather can do so via JS access.

The current code I have running is as follows:

```
$('.cart-product-qty').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend("QTY: ");
});
```

But the problem I just ran into is when certain functions are performed in the shopping cart it doesn't refresh, so it ends up dropping the QTY text. Is there another method so that it keeps it there continuously even if the page "refreshes"?

Comment: This really isn't the way of doing things. You should do this to your base HTML by asking the access from an authorized person.  Anyway, if those functions are resetting your QTY text then you should again add QTY by the same method again after the execution of those functions. By writing the code in on the load, I am not sure that will solve your problem as some other functions might run in the future on load after your code execution. If you are looking for on load doc https://api.jquery.com/load/.

Answer (score -1):

Listen to the parent `div` underneath the products will be listed. So whenever the content changes, you can trigger your function.

DOMSubtreeModified event might be helpful.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('div');

element.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', updateQtyText);

function updateQtyText(e) {
    $('.cart-product-qty').each(function() {
     $(this).prepend("QTY: ");
   });
}
```

Reference : [fire a call when inner HTML changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378194/fire-a-function-when-innerhtml-of-element-changes).

This might help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Generally you should vote to close the question as a duplicate instead of linking to another question. Additionally, link-only answers are discouraged since the link may change. Instead, post the content of the answer here and leave the link for reference.

Comment: Yeah sure  , will look into it..