# JS not executing in order: Last command fires before first resolved completly

Tags: javascript, function

I have this script that will "rename" and reenable a certain DOM element that I broke on purpose

```html
<button id="mypxlbtn" onclick="myPXFDFunction()">Pixelfed</button>
<script>
  function myPXFDFunction() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('pixlframe', 'iframe');
    document.getElementById('mypxlbtn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
</script>
<pixlframe src="https://pixelfed.de/aoikurayami/embed" width="80%" height="800" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></pixlframe>
```

However the "hide button" JavaScript action fires BEFORE or at least MID the rename operation.
To my understanding this should be two asynchronous commands.

So why will this simply not work as intended?

Executed js with expectations of "in order execution"
Second function however fires earlier than anticipated

Comment: Where is the "hide" button? Where is the second function?

Comment: Also you'll need to fix the closing tag too, that `.replace()` call will only replace the first instance of the string "pixlframe".

Comment: If you are talking about the `mypxlbtn.style.visibility = 'hidden'` running before the frame's content has reloaded, there's a couple of things that cause that. Firstly, loading a frame is asynchronous - loading the data starts, and execution continues. It may take a few seconds to load the source of that frame, whereas setting the visibility is almost instant. Secondly, replacing the `innerHTML` of the whole body will (sometimes) result in the browser having to re-render the whole page (which can be slow)

Comment: Made snippet of code - not easy to discern if it functions properly as written IMHO.

Comment: As hinted above, the only `pixlframe` string that gets replaced is the one in the `<script>` content, not the tag ones.

Comment: Yes, Luke is close to my problem. But how can I fix it ? (The rest of the code works as intended)

Comment: You are probably going to need a mutation observer to handle the reflow after the DOM update from the `innerHTML` change. No time for me to do that but here is ONE of several related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47378194/125981

Answer (score 0):

Setting innerHTML causes the entire body to be rebuilt. Any event listeners you have added to elements in JavaScript will be lost.

In any case, the solution is either to make your change only by manipulating elements (not changing the html) OR add a timeout to the style you want to apply

```
<script>
  function myPXFDFunction() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('pixlframe', 'iframe');
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('mypxlbtn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 4);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How would the "manipulating elements" idea of yours be implemented ? (I'll take a look at your timeout snippet, however it runs with the risk of not being enough if the main call takes too long)

Comment: I tried your tieout suggestion. It doesn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: `setTimeout` is a "workaround" often used but in my experience it always crops up again (fails or takes too long etc.) it not being what I consider a "definitive" answer to the challenge at hand.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss re: setTimeout is a "workaround" < Agreed, and it's why in my own code I've replaced nearly everywhere where I was using innerHTML with manual JavaScript DOM manipulation. But since OP has included the DOM, but asked about using innerHTML, what I've posted is the best solution I am aware of

Comment: @Rye re: How would the ... < You need to find the pxlframe element(s) and replace them with iframes. Something like document.querySelector("pxlframe"), then create new IFRAME elements, insert one before each pxlframe element and then remove the pxlframe element

Comment: So we are talking multiple steps here ?

Comment: @Rye re: So we are talking multiple... Um, yeah? I don't understand your question.