# i want my code to run when the page loads on but onload doesnt work

Tags: javascript

so here is my html :

```
                <div id="MyClockDisplay" class="" onload="showTime()"> 

                    clock

                </div>
and its my java script :
 function showTime(){
let date = new Date();
let h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
let m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
let s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
let session = "AM";

if(h == 0){
    h = 12;
}

if(h > 12){
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
}

h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;    
setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerHTML = time;
```

}

when i insert onclick (in html ) the java script code works perfectly
but i want the clock to start workiing when my page loads
but onload is not working
could someone help me pls?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284379/which-dom-events-can-be-bound-to-a-div-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` is not a valid attribute of a `div` element (it only works for `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<link>`, `<script>`). If you want the JS to execute immediately after loading, move the `script` tag immediately under the element.

```html
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="" onload="showTime()">

  clock

</div>
<script>
  function showTime() {
    let date = new Date();
    let h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    let m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    let s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    let session = "AM";

    if (h == 0) {
      h = 12;
    }

    if (h > 12) {
      h = h - 12;
      session = "PM";
    }

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerHTML = time;
  }
  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
</script>
```